# How to enable full-text search in sqlite3 on Windows

Tags: c, sqlite, visual-c++

I have compiled sqlite on Windows 7 using Visual C++ 2008
enabled FTS4 in the 'sqlite3.c' file as follows

```
#ifndef SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS
#endif
```

The debug version works fine but the release version fails with the error
'no such module FTS3' when trying to create a table

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE DOCS USING FTS3(DOC_NAME, DOC)
```

What is going on?

Comment: Your release and dev configurations probaly differ.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

section **2. Compiling and Enabling FTS3 and FTS4**

> If using the amalgamation autoconf based build system, setting the CPPFLAGS environment variable while running the 'configure' script is an easy way to set these macros. For example, the following command:

`CPPFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS" ./configure <configure options>`

where  are those options normally passed to the configure script, if any.

> Because FTS3 and FTS4 are virtual tables, The SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 compile-time option is incompatible with the SQLITE_OMIT_VIRTUALTABLE option.
>
> If a build of SQLite does not include the FTS modules, then any attempt to prepare an SQL statement to create an FTS3 or FTS4 table or to drop or access an existing FTS table in any way will fail. The error message returned will be similar to "no such module: ftsN" (where N is either 3 or 4).
>
> If the C version of the ICU library is available, then FTS may also be compiled with the SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU pre-processor macro defined. Compiling with this macro enables an FTS tokenizer that uses the ICU library to split a document into terms (words) using the conventions for a specified language and locale.

`-DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU`

Comment: That is exactly what I have done. I have read over that section many times over still have no idea why I am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 10. I tried to compile a shared library but I got the following error:

```
gcc -Os -shared -I. -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_EXPLAIN_COMMENTS   -DHAVE_USLEEP -DHAVE_READLINE  shell.c sqlite3.c -ldl -lreadline -lncurses  -o sqlite3.dll
```

> C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldl
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Then I tried without `-ldl` and it worked.

```
gcc -O3 -shared -I. -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_EXPLAIN_COMMENTS   -DHAVE_USLEEP -DHAVE_READLINE  shell.c sqlite3.c -lreadline -lncurses  -o sqlite3.dll
```